# Can Integer in URL be typecasted to String in Query Param?

Tags: rest, query-string

For the request

http://xyz/resource?articleid=232&name=John

```
Response getDetails(@QueryParam("articleid") String articleid,(@QueryParam("name") String name){}
```

Is the above Query Parameter correct for the given URL?

Answer (score 2):

Executive summary: there is no "integer" in the URL; there's only a string.  The implementation is does extra work to convert the string into an integer if you ask it to do so.

> Is the above Query Parameter correct for the given URL?

That should be perfectly acceptable.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4

`query` is a just a sequence of pchar (plus '/' and '?'), which is to say it's just data.

A query in that form is usually an expression of an [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#application/x-www-form-urlencoded) resource.  The key hint in the specification is

> Let output be an initially empty list of name-value tuples where both name and value hold a string.

The [JAX-RS specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1540296669_cc2fa6aaa3afc286f227115cb826e2c7) describes the transformation of these string to other types, but it defers to the java doc for the annotation.  Of course, [QueryParam](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) is in close alignment with the specification, so both places give the same answer.